# Is this a valid PMF question?

Tags: statistics

Suppose that the random variable Y : Ω → R where Ω = N is given by Y(n) = n .
Find E(Y), Var(Y) if the probability mass function of Y is given by :

\begin{equation}
  p(x) = \left \{
  \begin{aligned}
    &\frac{31}{108}x^x, && \text{if}\ x=2,3 \\
    &0, && \text{otherwise}
  \end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}

Compute the values of E(2Y + 1) and V ar(2Y + 1) as well.

How does this question work if the sum of the pmf values is over 1?
I calculated the sum as,
\begin{equation}
  P(x) = (2*\frac{31}{108}2^2) +( 3*\frac{31}{108}3^3) = 10.0463.
\end{equation}

Or am I misunderstanding something? I thought that if the sum of probabilities of a pmf function is over 1, then it cannot be a pmf for a rv.

Comment: No, this is not a valid probability mass function because $$ p(2)+p(3) = \frac{31(2^2 +3^3)}{108}>1$$ In fact $p(2)>1$ and $p(3)>1$.

Comment: @Michael

So if the pmf is invalid then what am I even doing here?

Can and should I even calculate the E(Y) Var(Y), etc. if Y is not a valid rv with a valid pmf?

Comment: There seems to be a typo or mistake in the problem.  I would not spend too much time worrying about it.  Just skip that problem or, if it is a homework, ask your teacher to clarify it.

Comment: @Michael 

Okay I'll take your word for it. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Michael 
It was a typo, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The pmf of $2Y+1$ is not $2p(x)+1$, it is $p(\frac{1}{2}(x-1))$ (the relationship here is computing $F(Y)$ you get pmf $p(F^{-1}(Y))$, so when you sum over the probabilities you will get the same numbers just located in different places. What you computed was $E[2Y+1]$, not $P(x)$.